# Google API Street View Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add to each of the markers I plotted on to the Google map that when you click the marker, it will show you the street map.

```
for(var i = 0; i < mapPoints.length; i++)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mapPoints[i],
        map:map,
    });

    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: mapPoints[i],
        pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
        }
    };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
        function(){
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), panoramaOptions);
            map.setStreetView(panorama);
        }
    );
}
```

However, all the markers when clicked, shows only the street view of the last marker.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're creating your markers in a loop.  However when you click a marker, it creates a `StreetViewPanorama` using whatever `panoramaOptions` is at the time of the click, not based on what it was at the time you were looping over the markers defining the event listeners.  So it will always be equal to its last-set value.

Try this instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < mapPoints.length; i++)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mapPoints[i],
        map:map,
    });

    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: mapPoints[i],
        pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
        }
    };

   defineEventListener(marker, panoramaOptions);
}

function defineEventListener(marker, panoramaOptions) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
        function(){
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), panoramaOptions);
            map.setStreetView(panorama);
        }
    );
}
```